# Should I finalize my statements if the SQLite database is reported to be corrupt SQLITE_CORRUPT

Tags: sql, delphi, sqlite, finalization

I recieve SQLITE_CORRUPT error for the database being corrupt.

```
wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_Settings_1
```

In my code I have a try/finally clause in which I always try to always sqlite3_finalize my statements.

Apparently on a corrupted database trying to finalize the statement raises again SQLITE_CORRUPT.

Question: Should I finalize my statements if the database is reported to be corrupted?

Comment: if you have a corrupt db, whether or not you finalize a particular statement is the least of your worries.  something has gone very, very wrong and you need to find out what.

Answer (score 1):

before sqlite3_finalize or after every sqlite3_step use sqlite3_reset.

The sqlite3_reset(S) interface resets the prepared statement S back to the beginning of its program.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have sqlite3_reset after every sqlite3_step because this is one case that causes database to be corrupt. after preparing a statement with sqlite3_prepare and executing it with sqlite3_step,you need to always reset it with sqlite3_reset.

> The sqlite3_reset(S) interface resets the prepared statement S back
>   to the beginning of its program.

before sqlite3_finalize or after every sqlite3_step use sqlite3_reset.

hope this solves your problem...!!!